# Problem With Tensorflow ,Tried with all versions ,current using Tensorflow version 2.00a0 ,python 3.6 Any idea Regarding this?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Tensorflow version 2.00a0 ,Python 3.6,IDE PyCharm
installed tensorflow framework using

python -m pip install tensorflow --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org

Upgraded using,

pip install tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0

This is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Athish/PycharmProjects/new1/Dashboard.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

  File "C:\Users\Athish\PycharmProjects\new1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import audio

  File "C:\Users\Athish\PycharmProjects\new1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\audio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav

  File "C:\Users\Athish\PycharmProjects\new1\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *

  File "C:\Users\Athish\PycharmProjects\new1\venv\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor

  File "c:\users\athish\pycharmprojects\new1\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: what version of `tf` are you using?

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Comment: Tensorflow version 2.00a0